# ISO file size correct?

Tags: software-installation, iso

I tried to download Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop 64 bit, and got 3 ISO images named:

```
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64 (1).iso
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64 (2).iso
```

All with file size 2.0 GB (1,953,349,632 bytes).

Questions - Does this seem correct, and do I just use one?

Thank you,
J2B

Comment: See:  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: You only use one.  It looks like you downloaded it 3 times.

Comment: Not sure how that happened, but you must be correct since the file sizes are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad idea to determine whether the ISO is correct is or not by merely looking at the file size. Since your file size is 1,953,349,632 bytes which is approximately 1.8 GB can be legit or not. The proper way to check whether the downloaded file is correct or not is using [Checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).

The original file checksum can be obtained from [Ubuntu Releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) under corresponding release folder and the checksum of the downloaded file (here ISO) can be calculated using below commands on Ubuntu/Linux and whether the file is legit or not can be determined by comparing the same.

1. For MD5SUMS:

   ```
   md5sum ISOName
   ```
2. For SHA1SUMS:

   ```
   sha1sum ISOName
   ```
3. For SHA256SUMS:

   ```
   sha256sum ISOName
   ```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be correct. If you want to be 100% sure you can check the [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the file. Open a new terminal and execute:

```
md5sum ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Then compare the received value with the value provided in the file [`MD5SUMS`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/MD5SUMS) from the download page of [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/).

Download that file and then use the `md5sum` command with `-c`ompare option to do this check:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/MD5SUMS
md5sum -c MD5SUMS
```

- *`md5sum` will generate a bunch of warnings. Don't worry: the OK message will be buried somewhere within it!*

Example (with suppressed error messages):

```
$ ls -l | grep 'ubuntu.*iso\|MD5SUMS'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 spas spas         138 юли 26 19:56 MD5SUMS
-rw-rw-r-- 1 spas spas  1953349632 ное 27 01:01 ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso


$ md5sum -c MD5SUMS 2>&1 | grep 'OK'
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy, I've updated the answer. In the downloaded file `MD5SUMS` have more than one md5sums and the command will output some error messages, by using of `2>/dev/null` these error messages will be suppressed.